# How to get Email ID from oAuth 2.0 using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, google-plus

My Question is basically How to get Email ID from oAuth 2.0  using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow ?

I am using MVC 4 application with GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow for oAuth 2.0 implementation.
After the page goes to the google and the user enters Email ID and password.

How could i Get the Email ID from the API?

Answer (score 1):

After authorization in googleapi. You will get acees_token,refresh_token etc along with id_token. The id_token is a string contains email field. But it is base64 encoded format. So you have to decode the id_token string using base64_decode. The id_token is coantains 2 stirng appended by '.'. The scond string contains the meat data of email,cilent id etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are many oauth scopes that give you the email.
Search for them in the oauth2 playground. The newest one is the google+ scope ised for 'login with g+' and google recommends using that scope instead of the older ones.

Comment: where can i get Code Sample (MVC or .Net ) for getting the email address after user logs in Google authentication screen in oAuth 2.0 implementation..

Comment: I have done it earlier and in this site there is no reference related to my query. Regarding oAuth2 Playground i could not get any sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is found here. Link to the page is at the bottom of this post.

"The first step is to call #loadCredential(String) based on the known user ID to check if the end-user's credentials are already known. If not, call newAuthorizationUrl() and direct the end-user's browser to an authorization page. The web browser will then redirect to the redirect URL with a "code" query parameter which can then be used to request an access token using newTokenRequest(String). Finally, use #createAndStoreCredential(TokenResponse, String) to store and obtain a credential for accessing protected resources."

http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg-history/0dd03fb10eb0ec8e66259d5a19e712bb274b68bc/1.10.0-beta/jdiff/Google%20API%20Client%20Library%20for%20Java%201.9.0-beta/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.html

Comment: While linking to official docs is good, it might help to also explain with your own words why and how the actual question can be solved. Replicating text from other websites verbatim may also introduce copyright issues to SO.