# How to get Email Id after google plus authentication by oAuth 2.0 using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

I am using MVC 4 with nuget package "Google.Apis.Auth" for oAuth 2.0 Implementation.

How to get Email Id after google plus authentication by oAuth 2.0 using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow

Reference code or information about implementation required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Email ID from oAuth 2.0 using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408578/how-to-get-email-id-from-oauth-2-0-using-google-apis-auth-oauth2-flows-googleaut)

Comment: Dup. Read the guidelines